# spring crud repository find top n Items by field A and field B in list order by field C

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have in a Spring Repo something like this:

```
findTop10ItemsByCategIdInOrderByInsertDateDesc(List ids)
```

I want the first 10 items where category id in list of ids ordered by insert date.

Another similar query:

```
findTop10ItemsByDomainIdAndCategIdInOrderByInsertDateDesc(List ids, @Param Integer domainId)
```

Here I want that the domain id is equal to the given param and the categId to be in given list.

I managed to resolve it using @Query but I wonder if there is an one liner for the above queries.

thanks

**EDIT**
The top works fine. Initially I had `findTop10ItemsByDomainIdAndCategIdOrderByInsertDateDesc`. Now I want the results from a list of category ids. That's the new requirement.

**SECOND EDIT**
My query works for find the set o results where domain id is equal to a given param and categ id is contained in a given list. BUT I found out that HQL doesn't support a setMaxResult kind of thing as top or limit.

```
@Query("select i from Items i where i.domainId = :domainId and i.categId in :categoryIds order by i.insertDate desc")
```

The params for this method were `(@Param("domainid") Integer domainid,List<Integer> categoryIds)` but it seams that I'm alowed to use either @Param annotation to each parameter or no @Param at all ( except for Pageable return; not my case )

I still don't know how to achieve this think:
extract top n elements where field a eq to param, field b in set of param, ordered by another field.

ps: sorry for tags but there is no spring-crudrepository :)

Comment: Have you tried it without a `@Query`? Is the finder matching your domain object and are yo using a Spring Data version that has support for the `Top` keyword?

Comment: see the edit for clarification

Comment: for starters your parameters are in the wrong order... And please add the code of the `@Query`.

Answer (score 10):

The method to resolve your problem is:

```
List<MyClass> findTop10ByDomainIdAndCategIdInOrderByInsertDateDesc(Long domainId, List<Long> ids);
```

1. `Top10` limits the results to first 10.
2. `ByDomainId` limits results to those that have passed `domainId`.
3. `And` adds another constraint.
4. `CategIdIn` limits results to those entries that have `categId` in the passed `List`.
5. `OrderByInsertDateDesc` orders results descending by insert date before limiting to `TOP10`.

I have tested this query on the following example:

```
List<User> findTop10ByEmailAndPropInOrderByIdDesc(String email, List<Long> props);
```

Where `User` is:

```
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String email;
private Long prop;
```

Currently I would recommend using `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` for storing dates using Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Is is possible to create method for top n where `n` could be passed as parameter?
For e.g. `findTopNByEmailOrderByIdDesc(String email, Long n)`  @xenteros

Comment: It is documented that we can use `top` parameter and it works without Order desc, but fails with order by desc. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Comment: This behaviour seems to be bugged, see my issue — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65366365/spring-repository-auto-generated-method-select-by-given-top-number-order-by-f

Comment: @DmitriyPopov that's not bugged. It's because there is no `by` between field and desc.

`orderByFieldDesc` not `orderByFieldByDesc`