# Spring Repository auto-generated method: select by given top number + order by field desc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Spring version is `2.4.0`.

I have a `PlayerEntity` with `Integer totalRacesCount` field. I need to make the top of players of different top length ordered by `totalRacesCount` desc. Top size must vary.

I am trying to add a method in my `CrudRepository<PlayerEntity, Long>` to implement this.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result — this section states that we can pass a numeric value `top` to make the limit parameterizable. This is working, but only when not combined with `OrderByTotalRacesCountDesc`, i.e. it works for `Asc` sorting.

- Method for a single top 1 record, without `top` parameter is working: `PlayerEntity findTopByOrderByTotalRacesCountDesc();` — selects player with maximal `totalRacesCount`, everything correct.
- Method for a hardcoded top N records is also working: `List<PlayerEntity> findTop25ByOrderByTotalRacesCountDesc();` — returns 25 players with highest `totalRacesCount`.
- However, when I try to add an `int top` parameter: `List<PlayerEntity> findTopByOrderByTotalRacesCountDesc(int top);`, start of the application fails with non-expecting the `top` parameter:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List parser.repository.PlayerRepository.findTopByOrderByTotalRacesCountDesc(int)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
```

- I've also tried to omit `By` after `Top`: `List<PlayerEntity> findTopOrderByTotalRacesCountDesc(int top);`, but this obviously is an incorrect syntax and fails on treating `Desc` as property name:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List parser.PlayerRepository.findTopOrderByTotalRacesCountDesc(int)! No property desc found for type Integer!
```

I know I can implement the `@Query` and set `top` as a `@Param`. But is it possible to implement the task with the query auto-generated by method name? **The behavior looks like a bug actually.**

All the links I've found use `@Query` (JPA or native) to implement the `order by desc` sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was reading the documentation incorrectly:

> You can append an optional numeric value to top or first to specify the maximum result size to be returned.

This actually DOES NOT mean a "method parameter" that you can vary, but just a hard-coded number after `Top` in the *method name*.

**Solution:** I should use `setMaxResults` instead.

Comment: You could also simply add `Pageable` as a parameter